# Changing background and button colours on public facing pages (like contribution) in drupal

Tags: contribution-page

Is there and easy way to change the colours on contribution pages, the background shouldn't be blue?

Also the buttons are all white with white text till you wave your courser over them.

Is there a simple way I'm missing that doesn't require any knowledge of code?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal you could add a new theme, for example 'Bootstrap', and add the module 'Themekey' to Drupal.  Then in Themekey settings you can specify the Bootstrap theme to be used for a particular page. For example in the Themekey settings when 'drupal.node' = 'civicrm/something' then theme is 'Bootstrap'.  No coding required!

Comment: Thanks!

I think the theme for my public pages is bootstrap, but the info for the contribution page turns up on a blue background and the button colours almost cant be seen, like here https://chabadbattersea.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=5